# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php after refresh with angular 2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem when i refresh page. When user is logged in it navigate him to : `/home`, and thats it angular 2 route. And i get template from angular. But when i refresh page i get an error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Problem is that laravel now try to get that view,but i dont have it. Any suggestion how can i fix that. When i add that view in laravel, i get blank page when i refresh or when i go to /home.

```
      <my-app>
                    <div class="loader">
                        <img src="{{asset('images/loader-img.gif')}}" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </my-app>

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.php` you can add following route at the end of file -

```
Route::any('/{any?}', 'PageController@app')->name('pages.app')->where('any', '.*');
```

And in the `PageController@app` you can return the HTML page of angular.

**Update**

Try by adding following route -

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: i dont have angular page i have component where i have template

Comment: Can you show the Laravel route on which your angular app works?

Comment: thats it ...tnx :)

Comment: Great, just remember to add it at the end of your route file otherwise, it will take preference over other routes